# ImportError from Raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

When I run my python3.7.3 code on the rapberry, when I call a specific function I get the following error from one of the imported libraries:

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/blis/cy.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_load_8

[image]

I control the raspberry from an ssh terminal

I thank those who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You have imported it as .cy, It is not possible. I think that is not the solution but it is not also the right way as no module can start with .
Also please provide additional information about which module are you trying to import and the python version.